# How to partition the mysql results by UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, smarty

news_table:

```
id (PK)    
title (varchar255)
time (INT 10) (UNIX timestamp)   
content (text)
```

I want to display group by one date

Like this format:

```
2014-12-16 << NEWS >>

title 2....   
title 1....

2014-12-15 << NEWS >>

title 1....

2014-12-09 << NEWS >>

title 3....    
title 2....    
title 1....
```

I'm using `smarty`.

Do I need to do something in `smarty` `html`  or  `php`  or  `mysql`?

Comment: for formatting like this, PHP or Smarty, and i would recommend adding smarty to your tags.

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend using a datetime or timestamp field for `time` ratherh than store UNIX timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group them into diffirent arrays in php and make a nested loop in smarty to get the data.

The php code might look like something like this:

```
<?php
    $data=array();
    /* a query which orders by date*/
    while($fetch=/*your code to fetch*/){
        $date("d-m-Y",$fetch["time"])
        if(!array_key_exists($date, $data)){
            $data[$date]=array();
        }
        $data[$date]=$fetch;
    }
/* your code to send to smarty*/

?>
```

the smarty code:

```
{foreach from=$myArray key=k item=v}
<h1>{$k}</h1>
    {foreach from=$v item=d}
     your item html
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks your smarty ref.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need something like this. First get all news into an array, with key of the date what you mentioned. Then loop through this array. Code is not tested.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY time DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$newsArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $row["time"]);
    if (!array_key_exists($date, $newsArray)) {
        $newsArray[$date] = array();
    }
    $newsArray[$date][] = array(
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'content' => $row['contntent']
    );
}
$oldDate = '';
foreach ($newsArray as $key => $news) {
    if ($oldDate !== $key) {
        echo "<p><strong>" . $key . " << NEWS >></strong></p>" . "\n";
        $oldDate = $key;
    } else {
        foreach ($news as $oneNews) {
            echo $oneNews["title"] . "<br />" . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```